# SQL - Optimization - Select those that do and do not satisfy a condition into 2 separate tables

Tags: sql

To select those that do and do not satisfy a condition into 2 seperate tables I can use the following:

```
select * from myTable where someThing=value  into qMatchCondition
select * from myTable where someThing<>value into qNotMatchCondition
```

However I expect this would be a waste of time! I.E. When SQL interprates the code will it not do something like this:

```
results = []
database.getTable("myTable").records.foreach(record){
   if(record.someThing == value){
       results.push(record)
   }
}
QueryTable.new("qMatchCondition",results)
results = []
database.getTable("myTable").records.foreach(record){
   if(record.someThing != value){
       results.push(record)
   }
}
QueryTable.new("qNotMatchCondition",results)
```

When writing the algorithm manually I would do something akin to the following:

```
results1 = []
results2 = []
database.getTable("myTable").records.foreach(record){
   if(record.someThing != value){
       results1.push(record)
   } else {
       results2.push(record)
   }
}
QueryTable.new("qMatchCondition",results1)
QueryTable.new("qNotMatchCondition",results2)
```

I expect this would depend on the SQL engine you are using, but are there any ways to force the SQL engine to "compile" to an optimized algorithm? Or do SQL engines generally compile statements anyway?

Comment: If you have two target tables, then generally you would need two separate queries to populate those tables.  That being said, you may _speed up_ those select queries by doing things like adding an index on the `someThing` column.

Comment: Why would you even be breaking a table into two separate tables?  That generally doesn't make sense from a performance perspective.  An index is unlikely to be helpful, although a clustered index or partitions on the original table might help.

Comment: @GordonLinoff [An Example](https://gist.github.com/sancarn/2bd5ad4136ab293c8168f410f3677756), I'm sure there are other examples also. This is just one I am currently writing. To be fair the SQL engine we use is already limited. E.G. there are no `Update ... where` statements, although that would still not be optimal. Ultimately those 3 seperate tables CAB, KST, and PLT go to 3 seperate processes where further data processing occurs.

Comment: @Sancarn . . . That seems like an unnecessarily inefficient approach.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I'm all ears for other approaches.